# Why x.func1 x.fun2 x.func3 functions do not work in onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This my code

```
function App() {
  const x = {
    value: 10,
    func1() {
      console.log(this.value, "111");
    },
    func2: function() {
      console.log(this.value, "222");
    },
    func3: () => {
      console.log(this.value, "222");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={x.func1}>1</h1>
      <h1 onClick={x.func2}>2</h1>
      <h1 onClick={x.func3}>3</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created an object X, it has 3 functions `func1, func2, func3`.
Why x.func1, x.fun2 x.func3 functions do not work in onClick ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `func1` and `func2` are not bound to `x`, and when called as event handlers, `this` is `undefined`. `func3` is an arrow function, and gets  `this` from the [enclosing lexical scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), which is the `App` function. The `this` value of a function depends on wether or not it's called in strict mode - see [Function Context on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context).

Point to `x` instead of `this`:

```js
function App() {
  const x = {
    value: 10,
    func1() {
      console.log(x.value, "111");
    },
    func2: function() {
      console.log(x.value, "222");
    },
    func3: () => {
      console.log(x.value, "222");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={x.func1}>1</h1>
      <h1 onClick={x.func2}>2</h1>
      <h1 onClick={x.func3}>3</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Example of arrow function on a literal object:

```js
const x = {
  func3: () => {
    console.log(this === window); // this points to the enclosing lexical scope, which is window
  }
};

x.func3();
```

Comment: Hello, are you sure about func3? I wrote `console.log (this, "222");`.And I get  `undefined "222" `.

Comment: Yep `func3` "this" points to `App`, which is a function and doesn't have `this` (in strict mode).

Comment: I do not have a strict regime.

Comment: The transpilers (webpack) usually adds them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic problem of ***this*** binding in Javascript.

For each function, why don't you try to `console.log(this)` and you'll see that this is actually bounded to the window, rather than the object instance of x.

You have two solutions:

Redefine each function as an arrow function, so this is appropriately assigned to the parent object, which is x in this case.

Or, you may use bind:

```
<h1 onClick={func3.bind(x)}>3</h1>
```